# How can I test/install an untagged version of a composer package?

Tags: php, composer-php

I would like to test my private composer package on localhost without the need to commit a new tag to perform the test.

My package tree

```
   ├── composer.json
├── README.md
└── src
    ├── Controllers
    │ 
    ├── Models

    ├── Providers
    │   └── RouteGenericServiceProvider.php
    ├── Repositories

    ├── Routes
    │   └── generics.php
    ├── Services
    │ 
    └── Transformers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to what is suggested bey @Matteo, you can use an *inline alias* and reference a commit hash instead of a tag.

Assume that `x.y.z` is the version you have currently installed, and `#123abc` is the hash of the commit you would tag once successfully tested (probably `HEAD` of whatever the branch is you want to test), then run:

```
$ composer require "my/package:dev-master#123abc as x.y.z"
```

For reference, see:

- https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md#require-inline-alias

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Path` repository type](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path). From the doc:

> For instance, if you have the following directory structure in your
>   repository:
>
> ```
> - apps
> \_ my-app
>   \_ composer.json
> - packages
> \_ my-package
>   \_ composer.json
> ```
>
> Then, to add the package `my/package` as a dependency, in your
>   `apps/my-app/composer.json` file, you can use the following
>   configuration:
>
> ```
> {
>     "repositories": [
>         {
>             "type": "path",
>             "url": "../../packages/my-package"
>         }
>     ],
>     "require": {
>         "my/package": "*"
>     }
> }
> ```

Hope this help