# Is it possible to use Composer update without tagging version

Tags: laravel, package, composer-php, workflow, packagist

I'm coding a Laravel Package, and a very annoying thing is my workflow is that when I want to try my plugin in a new Laravel installation, ( I install it with `composer require "myplugin/myPlugin"` ), it is mandatory to tag in github a version, so packagist can get the latest change.

This is annoying because sometimes, even for a small change, I must create a new version, and I would like to follow [Semver](http://semver.org/) standart.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if i am correct you can something in the direction of 'master' or 'dev-master'

Comment: yes, I could do it the way you say! Tx! You can put it as answer!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test Composer Package in localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45680420/test-composer-package-in-localhost)